# "Thunderbird is already running" error every time I try to start Thunderbird, even if it is not running

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird

I cannot open Thunderbird. The process isn't running, but when I click on the icon, I get the the following error:

> Thunderbird is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Thunderbird process, or restart your system.

I've tried the following:

- Ending the task in Task Manager
- Deleting `parent.lock`
- Uninstalling Thunderbird
- Uninstalling Firefox
- Running Thunderbird in software "safe mode" and Windows safe mode

What can I do to fix this problem?

The problem looks more serious than expected. I do not see any Mail folder in my profile at `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Mozilla\Thunderbird`. I think I lost my email.

Comment: I added your extra comment detail to the question.  The path provided doesn't look right, `Thunderbird` is not in `Mozilla` normally.  Where is the `parent.lock` file you deleted?  And how were you able to end the task in task manager if the process wasn't running?

Answer (score 3):

You said you've tried ending the task in task manager, but have you tried ending the *process* in the task manager?

Does it ever work correctly, for example the first time after rebooting your computer?

Answer (score 2):

As Meraj al Maksud noted, it could be due to file permissions. On mac OS, there’s an additional annoyance: access control lists (ACL). Recently, whenever I copy something (with `cp -a`) from an external backup, it gets copied with access restrictions that aren’t visible in the usual `ls -l` output. Among many other problems, this led to Thunderbird insisting that it was already open.

You can remove all ACLs using `chmod -N`, so `chmod -N -R .` will remove all ACLs from the current directory and all its contents.

Answer (score 1):

While the steps you described seem inconsistent, the most likely cause is probably an inaccessible or missing profile. See the following documents for hints on this

- http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding#w_check-the-profile-folder-name-and-location
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use

I will update my answer with more details, when it becomes more clear, what you did exactly and which results you got.

Answer (score 1):

What I experienced yesterday must be a major bug in Thunderbird. I've lost all of my mail. The folder for my corresponding profile is completely gone in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

a Linux user here.

There is a possibility that the .thunderbird directory may have wrong permissions assigned so one may one to check that. I don't have any detailed idea how permissions work on Windows but on Linux my **.default** and **.default-release** directory had wrong permission and ownership. After I changed ownership from root to current user, my problem went away.

Also, assuming that Windows thunderbird profiles use similar structure as Linux, another reason maybe due to the existence multiple profiles directory (i.e. multiple instances of **.default** or **.default-release** directory) within the home folder of same user. In that case, one should keep only one instance of each directory that works and move the rest elsewhere.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Meraj al Maksud 's answer remind me that I just receive a thunderbird's apt upgrade, which change my `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin/thunderbird`.

I put my profile in other directory and symlink `~/.thunderbird` to it so my backup procedure would be easier.
I modify the apparmor config to allow thunderbird read symlinked directory,
so I have to modify the new apparmor again.

However I have not figure out how to update it now.
I just remove the symlink and move the directory temporary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall and delete everything to do with thunderbird, then reinstall, worked for me, lost mail, but it's all on gmail anyway.

Answer (score -5):

Download **Revo Uninstaller** and then uninstall Thunderbird with that. Then reinstall Thunderbird. Also use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to start Explorer, then browse to `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Mozilla` and delete the `Thunderbird` directory in there.

Oh, by the way, Windows has notoriously bad process management, so be careful not to mess with the operating system.

Comment: Will deleting my profile erase my email and configuration settings? What do I need to do to back that up first?

Comment: The problem looks more serious than expected. I do not see any Mail folder in my profile. I think I lost my email.

Comment: @Robert Yes, this would delete all your mail and settings so I cannot recommend these steps. Jonathan Reno should have put in a warning at least. The use of Revo Uninstaller is questionable also.